# How to obtain time since last user log on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, time, authentication

How to obtain time since last user log on Windows in C++ app?

We have functions like `GetTickCount64` and `QueryUnbiasedInterruptTime` to retrieve time since OS startup. But I can not find anything related to the user logon.

Can we use `GetSystemTimes` and divide `lpUserTime` to the number of logical cores in the system?

Answer (score 1):

Call [`NetUserGetInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654.aspx) with level = 2. This gives you a [`USER_INFO_2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371337.aspx) structure, which includes `usri2_last_logon;` (a DWORD holding a 32-bit UNIX time stamp--i.e., seconds since midnight, Jan 1, 1970).

Note that if you're in a domain, the domain controllers (at least the backup controllers) store the logon time individually, so to get the most recent you need to ask all the domain controllers and use the most recent time-stamp of the results you get.